# How to move Mail data to an SD card?

Tags: macos, mail.app, data-transfer, storage, sd-card

I have MBA 128 GB, and my local Mail cache is too large to be stored on the HD. 
Now, I have the external 16 GB SD card plugged in via compact Nifty adapter. 
It's always mounted.

How can I set up the Mail app to store its data on that SD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailboxes are stored in ~/Library/Mail. You can move this to your SD card then symlink the new location back to the original location.

1. Move ~/Library/Mail to your SD card.
2. Symlink the folder:

   ```
   ln -s /Volumes/SD/path/to/your/Mail ~/Library/Mail
   ```